# Result of two multipled columns in a datagridview row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have got this code which calculates the `summary of 2 multiplied columns` of all rows in `datagridview` and shows the result in `textbox`.

I have got a third column called `sum` in which I would like to show the particular result of each row. I'm sorry because I have no idea how can I do that, so I haven't tried anything yet. May you please show me the way?

Thanks everybody for your time,comments or answers.

```
private void vypocti_odvody(int price, int vat, int tot_rows2)
    {
        try
        {

        double outVal = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

        {
            outVal = outVal + (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value)/100) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[vat].Value) + (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value));
        }

     //   s_ub_celk.Text = (((a / 100) * b) + a).ToString();
        Convert.ToDecimal ( result.Text = outVal.ToString()) ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Chybové hlášení K3 " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }


}
```

Comment: Is it databound? If yes what is the `datasource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply give the value to the column by assigning it's `Value` property:

```
private void vypocti_odvody(int price, int vat, int tot_rows2)
    {
        try
        {
        double outVal = 0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            double localSum = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value)/100) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[vat].Value) + (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value));
            outVal = outVal + localSum;
            row.Cells[sumcolumn].Value = localSum;
        }
        Convert.ToDecimal ( result.Text = outVal.ToString()) ;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Chybové hlášení K3 " + ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Just substitute the `sumcolumn` name.

Comment: Thank you so much trippino. Nice to see you again. I will accept in 10 mins. This was trivial.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the answer in order to have only the localSum on the column and not the entire sum.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify your `foreach` loop like this:

```
double outVal = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    var sum = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value)/100) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[vat].Value) + (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value));
    row.Cells["sum"].Value = sum;
    outVal += sum;
}
```

you have to introduce new variable that will hold sum value of both cells to set it in the new cell and after that add it to total sum.

Answer (score 0):

datagridview has a property called columns from where you can see at which position your column "sum" is
but for you the most simple thing would be:

```
row.Cells["sum"].Value=10;
```